# when i run my python text game i get a attribute error i dont know how to solve

Tags: python

for my first python project, I decided to make a text game adventure but I have stumbled upon a bug I really don't know how to fix the error:

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sekou\Documents\school simulator game\aloysiusgame.py", line 248, in <module>
myPlayer.gender = player_gender
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'gender'
```

code:

```
question2 = "ben je een meisje of jongen?\n"
for character in question2:
sys.stdout.write(character)
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(0.05)
player_gender = input("> ")
valid_anwsers = ["meisje", "jongen"]
myPlayer.gender = player_gender
    print("Je bent een " + player_gender + "!\n")
    while player_gender.lower() not in valid_anwsers:
player_gender = input("> ")
if player_gender.lower() in valid_anwsers:
    myPlayer.gender = player_gender
    print("Je bent een " + player_gender + "!\n")
pass
```

edit the part where i define the player:

```
import cmd
import textwrap
import sys
import os
import time
import random

screen_width = 100

##### player setup #####
class player:
def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.gender = ''
        self.classyear4 = ''
        self.sociaal = 0
        self.educatie = 0
        self.emoties = 0
        self.location = 'c16'
        self.game_over = False
        myPlayer = player()
```

Comment: Can we see where you are declaring `myPlayer`?

Comment: You're probably assigning a string to `myPlayer` instead of a `Player` (or similar) object.

Comment: I have added the part where I define the player. i hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude here is what i am thinking you are trying to do hope it helps

```
myPlayer = {}
questions ={'name':None, 'age':None, 'gender':['man', 'woman']}


for question, valid_answers  in questions.items():
    correct = False
    error_msg =""

    if valid_answers == None:
        answer = input(question + '\n>')
        myPlayer[question] = answer
    else:
        while correct == False:
            answer = input(error_msg+question+'\n>')
            if answer.strip().lower() in valid_answers:
                myPlayer[question] = answer
                correct = True
            else:
                error_msg = ("Your answer is invalid \n")

for key, value in myPlayer.items():
    print("{}:{}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: thank you, had trouble understanding it first but after testing it and making a few small changes it worked.